# Exact same HTTP request results in text/html or application/json depending on server

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have a very simple `JsonResult` method on one of my controllers:

```
[AjaxErrorHandler]
public JsonResult ApplyBasic(ApplyBasicModel applyBasicModel) {
    if (ModelState.IsValid) {
        return Json(1);
    } else {
        throw new InvalidModelStateException(400, "A required field was missing", ModelState);
    }
}
```

I am calling this method with the **exact** same POST data on my development machine and beta machine and I am given a different response and content type.  My development machine returns the correct response (`application/json`) whereas my beta machine is returning `text/html`.

The `Web.config` is exactly the same in both environments.

What could be causing this difference?

**Edit**:  Here's the code for my custom error handler `AjaxErrorHandler`:

```
public class AjaxErrorHandler : FilterAttribute, IExceptionFilter {
    public string ErrorMessage { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<string> ModelErrors { get; set; }

    public void OnException(ExceptionContext filterContext) {
        if (filterContext.HttpContext.Request.IsAjaxRequest()) {
            filterContext.ExceptionHandled = true;

            //If an HTTP Exception was thrown, make sure the correct HTTP code is returned.  Otherwise, default to a 500.
            if (filterContext.Exception is InvalidModelStateException) {
                var invalidModelStateException = filterContext.Exception as InvalidModelStateException;
                filterContext.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = invalidModelStateException.GetHttpCode();
                ModelErrors = invalidModelStateException.ModelState.Values.SelectMany(e => e.Errors).Select(e => e.ErrorMessage);
            } else if (filterContext.Exception is HttpException) {
                var httpException = filterContext.Exception as HttpException;
                filterContext.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = httpException.GetHttpCode();
            } else {
                filterContext.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = 500;
            }

            filterContext.Result = new JsonResult {
                Data = new {
                    HTTPCode = filterContext.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode,
                    Exception = filterContext.Exception.Message,
                    Message = ErrorMessage,
                    ModelErrors = ModelErrors
                }
            };
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the content of the `text/html`?  Is it an error page?

Comment: Good question.  The content is simply: "Bad Request".

Comment: Check DNS and firewall?

Comment: There is no firewall and I don't know what DNS would have to do with this.  The request is making it to the server just fine; it's just giving me back a response that I'm not understanding.

Comment: You can get "Bad Request" back from a server if your website is configured for a specific host name, but the host header in your request is for something else.  In other words, the request to the web server must have the same host header as what is configured on the server for the website.

Comment: I am returning a 400 response code on my own; it's inside the method that I posted.  If I change it to a 404 or any other HTTP code, then that's what the response contains (still in `text/html`).

Comment: Can you post the whole HTTP request? header and all, between the two?  My guess is the `Accept` is different.

Comment: @DMoses - The HTTP requests really are exactly the same (aside from the host, obviously).  The `Accept` header is identical:  `*/*`.

Comment: Does the exception return correctly on the other box?  Or it just doesn't get an exception?

Comment: @DMoses - Yeah, the exception is returned correctly on my development machine.  The data I'm throwing at the server in both cases is exactly the same and should result in the 400 exception.

Comment: Ah crap. It was the framework getting in my way.  I added one line of code to my error handler and the data is returned as it should be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to add one line of code to my error handler:

```
filterContext.HttpContext.Response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors = true;
```

Apparently IIS was getting in the way and wasn't letting me return my own error content.  By specifying this bool, the JSON content is returned correctly.